# Modifing an existing Custom Post Type doesn't work?

Tags: custom-post-types, visual-editor

I have to update an existing CPT which needs to support editor

it was

```
  $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'annual reports', 'ledexpo2018' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Annual Reports', 'ledexpo2018' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 'editor',
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */ 
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );

    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'technical-issues', $args );
```

and i added editor to the supports parameter

```
'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
```

but after a restart and even a permalink update the editor window is not visible??

What do i need to check/do to get this to work??

Comment: Can you try this flush_rewrite_rules()?

Comment: Do you happen to be using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin with this post type?

Comment: @JacobPeattie i just looked at the setup and indeed i see the ACF plugin

Comment: Go into _Custom Fields > Field Groups_, open any field groups that you see and have a look down the bottom at the very last setting, _Hide on screen_, and see if _Content Editor_ is selected.

Comment: oh guys tx ......i found it:  ' remove_post_type_support' was at the bottom of the .php file